# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser selective root text

Tags: php, parsing

Hi there how can I get only selective text in this code whith simple php parser

```
<div class="body" style="text-align: justify;padding: 10px;">
        <a class="entekhab_lead2" href="/"> other text : </a>
        <br> I want this text <br>
        <div align="justify"> other text or elements <div>
        <div> other text or elemnets </div>
        and anything else....
</div>
```

I want just return this: **I want this text**

I try this

```
foreach($html->find('div') as $element) 
   echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

but it print every text.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are selecting each div and not the br tag which is what you wanted, try this

```
foreach($html->find('br') as $element) 
  echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, have a look at php [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). This function allows removing html tags with allowed argument.

```
ie. strip_tags($string, '<br><br/>');
implies remove all tags leaving <br>'s
```

Hope this helps.